# Register through API

Tags: laravel, api, registration

How to register through API in Laravel ?  I am getting error `"Only json request are allowed with header 'Accept': 'application/json'"`.

[image]

Comment: if you use the application/json header then you'll have to provide a JSON body attached in the request containing the login information and not query params

Comment: Thanks @Nazgot. Now I am trying like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/sejaY.png. But I am still getting errors. Thanks.

Comment: Again you are now passing them as form-data and not as a raw JSON body

Comment: Thanks @Nazgot. I am trying like this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbnLs.png . But still getting errors. What should I do ?

Comment: Can you show more of your login controller and routes?

Comment: try after setting Content-Type header to application/json as well

Comment: Thanks @Nazgot. Here is my registration function https://pastebin.com/DkdDaPnU.

Comment: Thanks @user3532758. Where should I set it ? Thanks.

Comment: @user3532758 I set it already. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNUUG.png

Answer (score 1):

I think I am replying too late but hope this helps.

You need to send data as this shown in image.

- Go to body
- Change Text to JSON (last option)
- Provide register info as JSON

[image]

When sending request from within code
if (using any javascript library) you need to use **JSON.stringify()** on body before sending request